# Gmsh cannot mesh element inside a volume

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make a mesh of a piece of beam with stirrup and bars, but I'm having some trouble with stirrup, it is inside the main domain, and I do not know how to solve it. I'm attaching the .geo file, hoping someone could help. Maybe there are other way to mesh it, I do not know.

```
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

// Input
Rectangle(1) = {0, 0, 0, 300, 300, 0};
Disk(2) = {50, 50, 0, 10, 10};
Disk(3) = {50,250,0,10,10};
Disk(4) = {250,250,0,10,10};
Disk(5) = {250,50,0,10,10};
Rectangle(6) = {30,30,146,240,240,10};
Rectangle(7) = {40,40,146,220,220,10};


// Start Operations
s() = BooleanFragments{ Surface{1}; Delete; }{ Surface{2,3,4,5}; Delete;};
ext() = Extrude{0,0,300} {Surface{s()}; Layers{10}; Recombine;};
st() = BooleanFragments{ Surface{6}; Delete;}{Surface{7}; Delete;};
Recursive Delete {Surface{7}; }
Extrude{0,0,10} {Surface{22}; Layers{10}; Recombine;}
BooleanFragments{ Volume{5}; Delete;}{Volume{6}; Delete;}

// Mesh Options all elements needs to be Hexa
Mesh.RecombineAll = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer; however, I think I identified the problem that probably causes the major troubles:

The circular extrusions (cylinders) touch the stirrup exactly at the vertices, thus creating complications to OpenCASCADE-based `BooleanFragments` operation.

The following code:

```
SetFactory("OpenCASCADE");

// Input
Rectangle(1) = {0, 0, 0, 300, 300, 0};
Disk(2) = {52, 52, 0, 10, 10};
Disk(3) = {52,248,0,10,10};
Disk(4) = {248,248,0,10,10};
Disk(5) = {248,52,0,10,10};
Rectangle(6) = {30,30,146,240,240,10};
Rectangle(7) = {40,40,146,220,220,10};


// Start Operations
s() = BooleanFragments{ Surface{1}; Delete; }{ Surface{2,3,4,5}; Delete;};
ext() = Extrude{0,0,300} {Surface{s()}; Layers{10}; Recombine;};
st() = BooleanFragments{ Surface{6}; Delete;}{Surface{7}; Delete;};
Recursive Delete {Surface{7}; }
Extrude{0,0,10} {Surface{22}; Layers{10}; Recombine;}
BooleanFragments{ Volume{5}; Delete;}{Volume{6}; Delete;}

// Mesh Options all elements needs to be Hexa
Mesh.RecombineAll = 2;
```

where I slightly shifted the cylinders to the inside (`50`->`52` and `250` -> `248`) should not have the meshing problem.

[image]

However, this disconnects the cylinders from the loop and modifies the problem drastically. Here is a zoom on the problematic part **in the original, unmodified** setup.

[image]

So, what you required from the CAD tool, is to handle the merging of those two surfaces (the loop and the cylinder) automatically using `BooleanFragments`, which might be problematic, especially if one has to take floating-point arithmetic aspects into account.